# Intermittent issue with Authorize.net charging a card but the order is not being registered in Magento

Tags: magento, authorize.net

I recently updated to Magento 1.9.4.1 and then this issue started with charging transactions but the transactions aren't creating an order.  The customer remains on the checkout page so the customer thinks nothing happened and clicks the submit order button two or more times. This creates multiple charges in Authorize.net (creating new order numbers). the only thing I see in the error log is this - which coordinates with the same transaction time as the orders:

```
2019-12-30T13:15:20+00:00 ERR (3):
exception ‘Mage_Api2_Exception’ with message ‘oauth_problem=token_rejected’ in /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter/Oauth.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php(83): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_Adapter_Oauth->getUserParams(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php(59): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_Adapter->getUserParams(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(152): Mage_Api2_Model_Auth->authenticate(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Server.php(103): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->_authenticate(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Request))
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/api.php(73): Mage_Api2_Model_Server->run()
#5 {main}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue and if so how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

after going through dozens of multiple charges we noticed a common thread was that the ones that were multiples were all checking out as Guest.  When I took out the Checkout As Guest option and forced them to register, this issue stopped.  I don't know why authorize.net would care if a customer registers first but the token errors disappeared after the change.